# NavigationLink to pages vanishes after set as welcome page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, global-navigation

I have publishing site with home.aspx as welcome page by default.
I have few pages created in "Pages" document library out of which I would like to make "Dashboard.aspx" as Welcome page.
Also, I have created a navigation link for all the pages present in "pages" doc lib, which shows up fine including link for Dashboard page.
But as soon as I change welcome page to "Dashboard.aspx" the link for Dashboard goes away.
I would like to keep links for all the pages in TopNavigationBar.

Can someone please advice how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Double check that all your pages are checked in and published. If a page isn't checked in and published it can cause the NavigationLink to disappear.

Comment: Not really, all the pages are checked in and published as a major as well.